# Using the geometric series to work out big o notation for resizing an array in a stack

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1+2+4+⋯+2k=1−2^(k+1)/(1−2)

Here, 2^k=N. You get

1+2+4+⋯+N=1−2N−1
2+4+8⋯+N=2N−2

As shown above the array is doubled every 2^k. But I still don't understand all the steps for my working out doesn't match above. Can someone give me a step by step working out and explanation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Begin with

> 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + 2<sup>k</sup> = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1

If 2<sup>k</sup> = N, then

> 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + 2<sup>k</sup> = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1 = 2 · 2<sup>k</sup> - 1 = 2N - 1

Hope this helps!